# how to test a common method in application_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an auth method and want to put it in my application_controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base  
  helper_method :check_cred

  def check_cred
    "within check cred"
  end
```

but if I do this

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationController do
  it 'should check_cred', task050: true do
    check_cred.should == 'within check cred'
  end
end
```

I get:

```
 undefined local variable or method `check_cred' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_9:0x007ff5e3e40558>
```

How would I call a method like this to test?

thx

Answer (score 0):

RSpec controller specs wrap [ActionController::TestCase::Behavior](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb), which provides some instance variables to be used during tests:

> **Special instance variables**
>
> ActionController::TestCase will also automatically provide the following instance
>   variables for use in the tests:
>
> `@controller`:
>         The controller instance that will be tested.

So you may be able to do the following:

```
it 'should check_cred', task050: true do
  @controller.check_cred.should == 'within check cred'
end
```

Alternatively, you could move this helper method out into a separate helper module, and use an RSpec [helper spec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-0/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec) to perform the test, which may prove to be a better way to structure this test.

Comment: Thx for answer - this sounds about right. Let me check this out later. One issue is that I need to access the params hash so not sure if the application_helper will let me do that. Need to go through my previous tests (and get lunch).

Comment: I believe you can access `params` in a standalone helper module method, but you can easily test that